# existence of a ball in a measurable set

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\lambda$ be a Lebesgue-measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be Lebesgue-measurable set with $\lambda(A)>0$. I know that the difference set $A - A$ contains an open ball $B_r(x)$. My question is if the set A also contains an open ball with $B_r(x) \subset A$ where $r>0$?

Comment: The difference set $A \setminus A$ would be $\varnothing$. That must be a typo?

Comment: The set of irrational numbers in $[0,1]$ contains no open ball.

Comment: @6005: I think $A-A=\{x-y:x,y\in A\}$ in this context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not necessarily. One interesting counterexample is a ["fat" Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set).